# Efficient computation of matrix exponential of trace zero matrix

Tags: matrices, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

I am looking for identities that may help with numerical computation of the matrix exponential ${\rm exp}(A)$ where ${\rm tr}(A)=0$. I am already aware of general-purpose algorithms for computing the matrix exponential.

I am particularly interested in the case where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$.

Comment: Numerically or symbolically?

Comment: Numerically. Post updated.

Comment: Since $A=B+C$, where $C=\frac 13\text{tr}(A)I$ and $B=A-C$ and these commute, there is no difference between calculating matrix exponentials with 0 trace and general trace.

Answer (score 2):

From the trace condition and Cayley-Hamilton it follows that the powers of $A$  satisfy a recurrence of the form

$$A^{n+3}= cA^{n+1}+(\det A) A^n$$,

for some explicit  constant $c$. You actually need to compute  the matrices $B_n=\frac{1}{n!} A^n$. From the above recurrence you deduce

$$(n+3)! B_{n+3}= c(n+1)! B_{n+1} + n! B_n, $$ from which you get the recurrence

$$B_{n+3}=\frac{c}{(n+2)(n+3)}B_{n+1}+ \frac{\det A}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} B_n. $$

Once you've computed $A^2$ and thus, $B_2$, you're in bussiness.

Comment: Hmm I don't think the first equation in your answer is correct. A counterexample is $A = [1 -1; 0 -1]$ -- there is no constant $c$ satisfying your identity.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial  $P(\lambda)$ of a $n\times n$ matrix $A$has the form $\lambda^n-{\rm  tr}(A)\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\det A$. Cayley-Hamilton says $P(A)=0$.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake.